# autofill input after subtract

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Hi i have this simple code with three inputs

totalofservices, totalontarget & totalofftarget

i would like the flow of the code to be like this

a. user key in total of services

b. user key in total on target (it should not be larger than total of services)

c. Total off target is fill up automatically ( totalof services - totalontarget)

this what i tried so far which is currently not working

https://jsfiddle.net/03oqrczh/4/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.totalofservices').keyup(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find(".totalontarget").val($(this).val());
    tr.find(".totalofftarget").val("0");
  });
});


 $('.totalontarget').keyup( getDiff);
function getDiff(){
    var num1=1*$('#totalofservices').val() || 0;
    var num2=1*$('#totalontarget').val() || 0;
    $('.total').val( num1-num2);

}
 </script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Zone 1</td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='form-control totalofservices' type='text' size='20'  name='totalofservices[]'>
    </td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalontarget form-control' type='text' size='20'  name='totalontarget[]'></td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofftarget form-control' type='text' size='20'  name='totalofftarget[]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zone 2</td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofservices form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalofservices[]'>
    </td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalontarget form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalontarget[]'></td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofftarget form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalofftarget[]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zone 3</td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofservices form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalofservices[]'>
    </td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalontarget form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalontarget[]'></td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofftarget form-control' type='text' size='20'  name='totalofftarget[]'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code below so that input values are calculated and set correctly. Key up event handler for totalontarger element was not working properly. I fixed that too.

**Replace your script block with this:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.totalofservices').keyup(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find(".totalontarget").val(0);
    tr.find(".totalofftarget").val("0");
  });

  $('.totalontarget').keyup(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');    
    var num1=tr.find(".totalofservices").val();
    var num2=tr.find(".totalontarget").val();

    if( num2 > num1 ) {
        alert( 'Total of Target must be less than Total on Services' );
    }
    else {
        tr.find(".totalofftarget").val(num1-num2);
    }
  });

});

 </script>
```

[**https://jsfiddle.net/cjf7m2ms/**](https://jsfiddle.net/cjf7m2ms/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.totalontarget').keyup(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find(".totalofftarget").val(  
    parseInt(tr.find('.totalofservices').val()) - parseInt($(this).val())    
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Zone 1</td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='form-control totalofservices' type='text' size='20'  name='totalofservices[]'>
    </td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalontarget form-control' type='text' size='20'  name='totalontarget[]'></td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofftarget form-control' type='text' size='20'  name='totalofftarget[]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zone 2</td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofservices form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalofservices[]'>
    </td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalontarget form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalontarget[]'></td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofftarget form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalofftarget[]'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zone 3</td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofservices form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalofservices[]'>
    </td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalontarget form-control' type='text' size='20' name='totalontarget[]'></td>
    <td><input style='text-align:center' class='totalofftarget form-control' type='text' size='20'  name='totalofftarget[]'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am not quite sure about the flow you've mentioning. Let me know if I got it wrong. Now it's calculating once the totalontarget is keyup.

Comment: Thank you bro..karlo's answer is what i intended to do